# Python selenium .get_attribute('innerHTML') returns value that differs from one in the page source

Tags: python, selenium

I'm parsing a table which contains URLs with Selenium.

Some URLs are not being processed the right way. For example:

1. How URL is displayed in source and on page: `http://domain.tld/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=25&view=next`
2. How URL is displayed after using `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` or by using `Copy element` in browser's inspection tool: `http://domain.tld/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&amp;t=25&amp;view=next`.

As you can see, in this case, it does add `amp;` after each `&`. How do I make the output exactly as in the first case? I tried using `innerHTML` and `text` as attributes. `text` returns None.

Code that gets URLs from table is below:

```
rows = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
                for row in rows:
                    fields = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                    url = fields[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

I'm using Firefox as browser here.

Answer (score 0):

UPD: `text` did not return values from rows that were not in the visible area (not sure about this one) o_O

Initially I used `html2text` library.

The following code returns data as intended:

```
from html2text import HTML2Text as H2T
  
rows = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
                    for row in rows:
                        fields = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                        url = H2T().handle(fields[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')).strip()
```